# VCSA 6.0 / lleno

Tags: vmware

Tengo un problema, tengo un vcsa appliance que esta funcionando pero no soy capaz de entrar a la consola por ssh, al parecer el disco esta lleno. necesito entrar en modo rescue pero no soy capaz de hacerlo, los pasos que realice son

- entrar en la maquina esxi desde alli modifique para que boot del iso
- La version que tengo es suse del appliance
- no reconoce el bash.

no se que mas puedo ejecutar para entrar en modo rescue para limpiar el disco.

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Yo mismo me respondo tenia que configurar la ISO con la maquina apagada, luego forzar el ingreso a la BIOS y luego cargar la MV desde el ESXi para poder acceder al panel del boot.

Saludos